# Closed form for the number of permutations with a given excedance set

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, closed-form-expressions

Let $q(n)$ be [A007814](http://oeis.org/A007814), i.e., number of trailing zeros in the binary representation of $n$. Here
$$q(2n+1)=0, q(2n)=q(n)+1$$

Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ be [A000120](http://oeis.org/A000120), i.e., number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ (or the binary weight of $n$). Here
$$\operatorname{wt}(2n+1)=\operatorname{wt}(n)+1,\operatorname{wt}(2n)=\operatorname{wt}(n),\operatorname{wt}(0)=0$$

Let $a(n)$ be [A329369](http://oeis.org/A329369). Here
$$a(2n+1)=a(n), a(2n)=a(n)+a(n-2^{q(n)})+a(2n-2^{q(n)}), a(0)=1$$

Let
$$T(0,1)=T(0,2)=1$$
$$T(0,k)=0, k>2$$
$$T(n,1)=1, n>0$$
$$T(2n+1,k)=kT(n,k)+T(n,k-1)$$
$$T(2n,k)=kT(n,k)+T(n,k-1)-\frac{1}{k-1}(T(2n,k-1)+T(n,k-1))$$

I conjecture that
$$a(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\operatorname{wt}(n)+2}k!T(n,k)(-1)^{\operatorname{wt}(n)-k+2}$$

Is there a way to prove it?